# Set min height but not max

Tags: layout, windows-phone-7

I have the following XAML code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NewsDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Width="400" Height="100" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <TextBlock x:Name="NewsText" Text="{Binding Text}" Margin="8,4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="384" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextGroupHeaderStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I want to NewsText TextBlock can be as height as it needs but also I want to set a minimum height:
NewsText will have 100 or higher height.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the MinHeight property...

[FrameworkElement.MinHeight Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight%28VS.95%29.aspx)